# Can I use Stack Overflow's icons on a personal site?

Tags: discussion, icons, stack-overflow, copyright

Per the terms of service (TOS):

> Subscriber may download or copy the Content, and other items displayed on the Network for download, **for personal use**, provided that Subscriber maintains all copyright and other notices contained in such Content.

I am guessing according to this, that's a, "No."

I want to just display a feed for my recent questions/answers and the icons for accepted answer or up-votes. Right now I use two icons from the main Stack Overflow sprite:

[image: Stack Overflow icon example]

It wouldn't be hard to make an arrow and a checkmark in *insert favorite image editor here*, but using the "official" ones was more convenient.

Comment: FWIW, [the loading icon may be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246115/193139).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Trademark Guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

> #### Use of Our Name or Logo in Advertising
>
> - Do use the most current logo where applicable and permitted.
> - Do use the proper name for our company, product, or service (see "Proper use of the Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange Name" below).
> - Do not use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.
> - Do not use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.
> - Do not use any name or logo that is similar to or might be confused with our name or logo.
> - Do not distort or alter our logo in any way.
> - Do not use our logo in a way that confuses our brand with another brand.
> - **Do not use any other artwork from our network without explicit permission**.

Comment: Thanks! I will roll my own icons.

Comment: @subkamran, FYI - http://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos