# Where is there a list and picture of all the icons used on the Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, icons

I am looking for a list the icons and explanatory sentence used on the Stack Exchange site. Does one exist?

The format I find useful is something like the lists shown at the various 'views' [on this site](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_outline_view.htm) on [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

One particular icon I am not sure of is when there are reputation points, +<n> in white surrounded by green. Normally the reputation points are green with a white background. The change in coloring is significant.

Having a table, like that one referenced, would quickly answer the question.

[image]

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Comment: @juergend I don't think he's referring to logo, but to icons like vote arrows or maybe editor buttons.

Comment: Yes, not logo, icons.

Comment: this question sounds off-topic but I wouldn't know for what reason as demonstrate a minimal understanding wouldn't apply here and it's quite clear what you're asking for but can you elaborate on the purpose of the list of icons with *explanation* ? Show an example of *explanation* you're looking for

Comment: What's the purpose?

Comment: The purpose is to help augment a Q&A, and, so if I forget I can look it up. :)

Comment: @KeithSmith do you mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bq0cu.png) in your edit?? Also, please use `@` to reply in comments.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's not an icon. It's pure and simple CSS: white text, green background. The rounded corners are achieved using such CSS: `border-radius: 3px;`.

Comment: Fine, then it is not an icon. What does the symbol, or glyph, or highlighted text mean? and where is the documentation on SO on this 'item'?

Comment: Green text (with white background) is the reward for the accepted answer. White text in a green box are upvotes.

Answer (score 21):

**Warning**: just in case you plan to use them on your own site, **[don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85962/can-i-use-stackoverflows-icons-on-a-personal-site)**. (they're trademarked)

There are several type of "icons", some are stored in CSS sprites (one big image with all of them, CSS is used to position proper icon as background) and some are made "on the fly" without actual image resource.

1. Editor icons can be found in this URL:https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/wmd-buttons.svg:

   [image]
2. [Favicons of all sites](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16.png):
   [image]
3. General icons (e.g. vote arrows, favorite star) are now made "on the fly" without actual image resource, e.g. to generate the upvote arrow, you can run this HTML code:

   ```
   <svg aria-hidden="true" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 26h32L18 10z"></path></svg>
   ```

Comment: That's a nice list of icons. I appear to have not been clear in my question. I was looking for a list of icons AND an explanatory sentence for each icon, like the Eclipse icon listing I referenced in my question. I will update my question.

Comment: @KeithSmith I'm pretty sure such thing does not exist. But most icons are quite self explanatory, which of them you need help understanding?

Comment: Yes most of them are self explanatory. What about the +<number> which is surrounded by color. i.e. +10 with +10 in white and surrounded by green.

Comment: @KeithSmith can't see any +10 in white/green anywhere. What do you mean? Can you give example or screenshot?

Comment: No. Sorry this not my 'edit'. I have added a screen shot to the original question.

Comment: @KeithSmith yep, figured it now.

Comment: The icons are very similar to [Silk Icons pack](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/).

Comment: @n.1 maybe it was the designer inspiration, yep.

Comment: +1 I love detective work

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's gone now.

Comment: This answer is mostly broken.

Comment: @Laurel thanks for the heads up, answer updated.