# MathOverflow links on Mathematics Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, internal-links

Sometimes on Mathematics Stack Exchange, I would like to reference a link from MathOverflow.  It would be helpful if it got immediately turned into the title without having to type it and then include the hyperlink, i.e.:

```
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145606/on-the-pathwise-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-sdesstochastic-differential-equation
```

versus

[On the pathwise uniqueness of solutions of SDEs(Stochastic Differential Equations)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145606/on-the-pathwise-uniqueness-of-solutions-of-sdesstochastic-differential-equation).

---

(I posted on Meta Mathematics SE (in this question: [Mathoverflow links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36057/mathoverflow-links?noredirect=1#comment170088_36057)), but I was advised to try here.)

Note that even here at Meta.SE just including the MO link leads to immediate conversion to the title (as above).  So I imagine it should be possible to do the same for MSE.

**Update:** Yes, even though there is a similar question [Parse question links from other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251183/parse-question-links-from-other-se-sites), this question was not answered either officially:

> This would be a great feature to have the titles automatically added cross-site, but till then, I've made a userscript. It will convert the URL to its title (with a minor delay).

I am guessing since eight years have passed, there were other priorities or does it really cost that much processing power (more than holding images or processing LaTex)?

Comment: This seems similar to this feature request: [Parse question links from other SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251183). (The difference being that this about specifically about [math.se] and [mathoverflow.se], the other feature request is about all sites.)

Comment: Wait, why does this work on Meta SE, though? I had no idea that that was the case.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist See: [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108134) The answer says: "On Meta Stack Exchange, all sites work." and "On all meta sites, links to Meta Stack Exchange work." (I did not know about that either - but I tend to use `[text](URL)` for links to questions and answers.)

Comment: Thanks, @Martin, that information is new to me :)

Comment: I have added the tag ([tag:internal-links]) - the [tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-links/info) says that this tag is for: "Questions involving the automatic conversion of Stack Exchange URLs into question titles when included in a question or answer."
If this question is specifically about those two sites, one might consider adding the tags ([tag:math-se]) and ([tag:mathoverflow]).

Comment: I imagine the reason it doesn't just work _everywhere_ for _all sites_ is that it requires processing and that processing isn't free. So they do it where it is most commonly used (and useful), but not everywhere.

Comment: @Martin I am guessing since eight years have passed, there were other priorities or does it really cost that much processing power (more than holding images or processing LaTex)?